# Breaks a couple of lines after breakpoint

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am developing a C application using Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu VM.

I am facing an annoying issue when debugging, here is a pic that explains the problem

[image]

The **RED** arrow shows where my breakpoint actually is, the **BLUE** line shows where Eclipse breaks the execution! I researched this issue and the only thing I found was that the compiled exe and sourcefiles might not be matching/same but as you can see at the bottom (**highlighted in yellow**) they are the same!!

The funny thing is that some other breakpoints do break correctly, and I have no idea why some would while others wont!

Any ideas?

Comment: It should break when it will enter the `for` loop and `if` condition evaluates to `true`.

Comment: have you tried a clean and fresh build?

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes it didnt help

Comment: @dbasic yes but thats not whats happening its breaking on the following line after the `if` and `for`

Comment: Which version of CDT you are using?. Raised similar bugs [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425062) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425072). If you agree please vote up for these bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you aren't using any optimizations. Optimizations will cause the code to be transformed by the compiler in such a way the IDE/debugger can't compensate for.

Comment: I didnt think of that..will try it

Comment: I disabled the optimization and still have the same problem any other ideas

Comment: Not really. Your IDE could be off-by-one.